# Implementation logic of H/W prefetcher in Core-i3/i7

Tags: x86, cpu-architecture, prefetch

I have two questions related to H/w prefetcher in Intel Core i3 /i7 .

1. How many memory lines are prefetched once a fixed stride is detected by H/w prefetcher in Core-i3 /i7 ?  Is it only next index or multiple cache lines ?

For example, if I access 0,2,4,6 index , will only 8th index or 8,10th or more index will be prefetched ?

2. How Core i3/i7 still manage to prefetch data when there is no fixed stride exist ( for example when data is accessed randomly)?

When I access indexes in random sequence as below `4,8,72,16,32,64,54,34,68,62,50,26,52,30,60,46,18,36,70,66,58,42,10,20,40,6,12,24,48,22,44,14,28,56,38,2,0`

then how H/w prefetcher is able to prefetch all below indexes

`18 22 28 34 38 44 50 56 58 72`

I am trying to understand the behaviour of H/w prefetcher.

I heard about some forward or backward stride detector , but not able to understand how those forward or backward stride detector store the already accessed index and how they calculate to prefetch next cache lines or when they activate ( after first or 2nd miss or more ).

Any link or idea to investigate will be great help.

I have posted another question [How to defeat hardware prefetcher in core i3/i7 in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31930421/how-to-defeat-hardware-prefetcher-in-core-i3-i7-in-linux) , however that concept was true for Core2Duo , not for Core-i3/i7.

Any Intel document or other source from where I can understand the logic of H/w prefetcher implementation will be a great help.

Comment: Which micro architecture (e.g. Haswell)?

Comment: cat /proc/cpuinfo shows Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz

Comment: Core-i3 machine details, Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2100 CPU @ 3.10GHz. In both system I am getting almost similar result.

Comment: That is not related to any programming language, compiler or OS.

Comment: @Olaf, I have written code in C to access those indexes in linux OS. My aim is to understand how the h/w prefetcher works so that I can write a code to defeat the h/w prefetcher (see other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31930421/how-to-defeat-hardware-prefetcher-in-core-i3-i7-in-linux ) and compare the performance of system without h/w prefetcher ( disable manually vs defeat programmatically ).

Comment: And how is that related to a hardware-only question? As given, it is not even about programming at all (but as it is related, I did not vote to close). However, as it might be relevant to programming in general, I think it is valid as-such - yet language/OS-agnostic.

Comment: Your indexes are exceeding 64, so I understand they're no 64B lines in a 4k page - so what are they? are 18, 20 and 22 even on different cache lines?

Comment: @Leeor, I am accessing data of 5KB [i.e.DATA[1028]={...}], so 0-63 index belongs to 1st 4KB page, whereas 64-79 index present in next 4KB page. I have checked in my system , cache line size is of 64Bytes by using cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index2/coherency_line_size (it gives 64). Also 18,20 and 22 present in different cache lines as I am accessing all indexes as below, for all random_index access address 16*random_index .